# How to write a graduate study personal statement for a technical field without related bachelors degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application-cover-letter

With the desire to obtain a master's degree in Management Information Systems, IT Management, or Computer Science, how do you proceed writing a personal statement when your bachelors degree is unrelated?

With minimal previous technical experience (basic knowledge on programming, some collegiate participation in software club), is it possible to be considered seriously? What can be added to the statement to strengthen your impression?

I ask because a lot of the [graduate ambassadors](http://www.cdm.depaul.edu/Prospective%20Students/Pages/Graduate-Ambassadors.aspx) at DePaul have bachelors in different fields.

Related: [How does one change to engineering for graduate school after undergrad in a science field?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/how-does-one-change-fields-between-undergrad-and-grad-school)

Comment: Hello @Garry, it has been a year since you ask this question. Can I ask that are you successful in the transition? Do you have any tip? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ooker Sorry Ooker, no followup to the question. I asked this question for a friend of mine and they chose to pursue other interests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was recently accepted to a MS program that is different from my undergrad and graduate training.  In my personal statement I tried to relate my experience to the field I was pursuing.  I had field research experience in public health, but I was applying for a MS in biology.  I still used my research experience, but I focused on the general research skills that I developed, things that would be useful in the lab.  I mentioned things that are universal to all research.

I think if you convey passion and direction for the new field, you'll be alright.  It can be an advantage too.  Think of ways you can incorporate your previous field if possible.  If not, show them your maturity and passion.  It seems like admissions committees can tell who is going through the motions and who is genuine.  Make your voice heard.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I applied for an MS in electrical engineering. I wrote my sop on my own.

Firstly you have to mention how you got interested in this field. Then you mention all about your academics and activities from your schooling to present day. Then you mention about your area of interest and your academic projects and internship(s). At last why you want to do graduation in the area you prefer to and conclude.
Regarding your projects you have to give brief explanation about the project and the things that you used in the project .

Comment: No, you *don't* mention "all about your academics and activities from your schooling to the present day." You only discuss _relevant_ information that helps the reviewer understand what you want to do as a graduate student (plus some motivation as to why). A blow-by-blow replay of your academic career is not particularly helpful—unless you have particular circumstances that require clarification or explanation (a gap in your career, poor performance at a particular stage of your career, absence due to illness, etc.).